# How to import sql in vb.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I mean the imports keyword on the uppermost part of the program.
What should I type in there?

Comment: I've got to wonder, if you can't read through the documentation or Intellisense to work out the right package name, how do you intend to figure out how to use the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Then here's an example of how to talk to the db:

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("Sql statements here")

    cn.Open()

    Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While rdr.Read()
            ''# Do stuff with the data reader
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

and a c# translation, because people were curious in the comments:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Sql statements here"))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // Do stuff with the data reader
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize you could use two variables in a using statement.  Does that translate to C# also?

Comment: Sort of: C# does allow this but the exact syntax is a little different.

Comment: The C# works because of the normal rules about { } blocks: if you only have one statement you don't need the braces.  You can also comma-separate multiple objects in a single using directive in C#, but when you do that they have to all be of the same type, so this typically works better.

Comment: For extra fun, try a `using () try \n { \n } \n catch() {}`

Answer (score 3):

You mean:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```